# Is it necessary to test for NULL if also testing for greater than?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I inherited some old stored procedures today, and came across several examples that followed this general pattern, where `@Test` is some `INT` value:

```
IF @Test IS NOT NULL AND @Test > 0
    -- do something...
```

My understanding is that if `@Test` is `NULL`, then it has no value, and is not greater than, less than or even equal to zero. Therefore, testing for `NULL` is redundant in the above code:

```
IF @Test > 0
    -- do something...
```

This second version seems to work just fine, and is far more readable IHMO.

So, my question: Is my understanding of `NULL` being unnecessary in this instance correct, or is there some obvious use-case I'm overlooking here where it could all go horribly wrong?

**Note:** In some cases, it was obvious that the intent was checking for the existence of a value, and I've changed those to `IF EXISTS`... my question is more concerned with the general case outlined above.

Comment: The test is not redundant. What if Test is null than what will the outcome of IF test > 0 be ?

Comment: `IF @test > 0` will be enough, unless you haven't other behavior if @test is null

Comment: I'd recommend experimenting with stuff like 'select case when null > 5 or null <=5 then 1 else 0 end' and what happens if you negate an entire condition with NOT - SQL has this '3 states' of true/false and then null - in my opinion you don't want NULL to be fed into it, unless you are prepared to always be very carefull what you do with NULL

Comment: @GuidoG If `@Test` is NULL, then the `IF` statement will be skipped, which is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare with NULL is necessary if you use ELSE statements:

for example:

```
declare @t int
set @t=null
if (@t>0) print '1' -- works fine
if (@t<0) print '2' --works fine

if (@t>0) 
    print '3' --works fine
else print '4' --here we start getting problems, because we are sure that @t<=0 that is obviously not true
```

Comment: Yes, that's a great point. As it happens, none of the code I've looked at so far follows that particular form, but it's definitely one use-case to watch out for.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, because it directly addresses the question by providing a plausible scenario where *not* checking for NULL might cause unexpected results. Thanks to everyone for contributing, there were a lot of helpful points raised.

Answer (score 9):

In SQL all comparisons to a NULL value evaluate to false.
So you always have to check explicitly for NULL, if you wish to act on it.
So, in this case, the additional test is not necessary.

Comment: Actually they don't evaluate to false, but to null which is casted to false, but this does not change the fact, you have to check it.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the slight wrong wording. The result of the comparison is NULL, which is not a boolean TRUE.

Comment: @Pred Why do you say "you have to check it", in this example?

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin I was in a rush, did not pay enough attention to the original question and taking care of nulls can not be a bad practice. This is the short story.

Answer (score 5):

@FlorianHeer is right on.  NULL > 0 will eventually evaluate to false but as @Pred points out that is because Null > 0 actually evaluates to null and null cast to a bit is false....

A null is an unknown and therefore any comparison with it is also unknown.  Think of arithmetic functions such as addition `1 + NULL = NULL`, or concatenation `'A' + NULLL = NULL`.  NULL means the SQL database engine cannot interpret what its value is so any function or comparison on it is also unknown.

@MikkaRin pointed out that it is the assumption in the ELSE portion of a case statement or IF statement where that can become problematic but lets also think about this in the context of a join and how you may or may not want to see the results.

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (Col INT)
DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE (Col INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (1),(NULL),(3),(4)

SELECT *
FROM
    @Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
    ON t1.Col <> t2.Col
```

Naturally you might think because NULL would be not equal to 1,2,3 that it should be included in the result set.  But null is unknown so SQL is saying well I don't know if NULL could be 1,2,3 so I cannot return that as a result.

Now lets do the same thing but add a NULL in the first table:

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (Col INT)
DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE (Col INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(NULL)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (1),(NULL),(3),(4)

SELECT *
FROM
    @Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
    ON t1.Col = t2.Col
```

Again you might think that NULL is = to NULL but any comparison of NULL is considered unknown so even though both tables have NULL in it it will not be returned in the dataset.

Now consider:

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (Col INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(NULL)

SELECT *, CASE WHEN Col < 2 THEN Col ELSE 1000 END as ColCase
FROM
    @Table1 t1
```

Which will make even the NULL 1000 the question is should NULL an unknown be 1000? if NULL is unknown how do we know that it isn't less than 2?

For a lot of your operations it may simply be enough to compare `@Value > 1` but especially when you start dealing with ELSE in case of IF statements or joining on the antithesis you should consider dealing with the NULLs.  Such as using `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` as @GuidoG points out.

**IMHO being explicit about your intentions during operations to appropriately account for null values out weighs the minimal savings of typing.**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples Matt, very useful. I guess the value for me (at least in the relatively simple use-case of the original question) is clarity. Usually, this is achieved through being explicit as you say, but the code I'm working with is flooded with `NULL` checks, arguably obscuring its greater purpose somewhat. The only cases being dealt with, it seems, are positive integers, so I suspect I don't need to be overly defensive about `NULL` checks. In that scenario, which of the two examples would you find clearer?

Comment: I would find "IF ISNULL(@Test,0) > 0" to be the most succinct and clearest.  It is a hybrid between your lean code and makes your intent of how to treat the null clear.

Answer (score 2):

you could replace it with

```
if isnull(@test, 0) > 0
```

This way it will be shorter and you still have checked everything

Answer (score 1):

another interesting example:

```sql
SELECT (null > 0) AS a, !(null > 0) AS b
```

value of both **a** and **b** will be **NULL**

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, in some cases null checks are added sometimes to short circuit `OR` logic. For example, consider the following:

```
select * from tbl where (@id is null or @id > id)
```

If you pass in a value for `@id`, it tests the first condition (`@id is null`) and sees that it's false, but since it's part of an `OR` statement, it then goes ahead and then runs the `@id > id` comparison to see what that one returns as well. `OR` statements only need one true returned for the whole thing to resolve to true, and must keep testing until it comes across an `OR` condition that does.

Whereas if you pass in `null` for the `@id` parameter, as soon as it gets to the first condition and it returns true. Seeing that the next it's part of an `OR` statement, SQL knows it doesn't even have to do any of the following comparison, because the entire `OR` statement has already resolved to true.  The `@id > id` comparison and will not even run it. This can save a ton of processing if it's a huge table or complex join, etc.